# Marklogic show whole query in console

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm debug my XQuery code, In MarkLogic console, I want to view the query statement.And I use such as below scripts:

```
cts:parse("cat OR dog AND mouse")
```

But it gives me below response:

```
cts:or-query((cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("", "ElementA"), "XXXX",("lang=en"), 0),cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("", "ElementB"), "XXXX",("lang=en"), 0), ...), ())
```

It use the apostrophe ellipsis(...) to display the result as it too long.

Is there any possible to show the whole query statement?

Comment: what is generating the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually now I see what you mean. If your query is larger you can use [xdmp:describe()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:describe)

```
xdmp:describe(
  cts:parse("cat OR dog AND mouse OR fly OR cow"),
5);
```

(modify the second parameter according to your needs)

**Old response**

Not sure why you see the '...' - for

```
cts:parse("cat OR dog AND mouse")
```

I get the full response:

```
cts:or-query((cts:word-query("cat", ("lang=en"), 1), cts:and-query((cts:word-query("dog", ("lang=en"), 1), cts:word-query("mouse", ("lang=en"), 1)), ("unordered"))), ())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in `document {}` which will make it return the XML representation:

```
document{cts:parse("cat OR dog AND mouse")}
```

HTH!